# ejabberd block communication from backend

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I have a scenarios where users in rosters are communicating with each other but sometime we have to block communication from backend between two users.

How to can I block communication in this way

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no way in ejabberd or in the existing modules to configure something like this.

The more similar thing I could find is an old module that allowed to block communication between vhosts, but it doesn't work in newer versions, and anyway it didn't really solve what you want: https://www.ejabberd.im/mod_filter/index.html and https://github.com/knobo/mod_filter